# Can we start making chat rooms for other specific crafts and concepts?

Tags: discussion, chat

I saw another room pop up for [Poster Design](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39304/poster-design). Should we start making more rooms for other specific crafts? A place for people to get centric knowledge about there craft and compare ideas and such?

Comment: I created that chat room.

Answer (score 3):

I know the creation of that room was done with the best of intentions and no harm was intended. However we should be careful about the dilution this could cause. This site is still young. We have a few regulars in the current chat room but it is by no mean a bustling metropolis of activity. Trying to create more rooms will easily spread to thin what we have.

We should wait until the chat room gains a lot more momentum before we start to split off. This site will thrive as a result of our collaboration now. With that in mind I think we should stick to the one main chat room.

[Quoting Robert Cartaino](https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/a/217/128), the Director of Community Development

> I wouldn't split your existing chat room to make another. If you are anticipating overcrowding in your main chat room, that's a pretty high-quality problem. But I wouldn't create even more underutilized spaces to handle people who have not materialized yet. Leverage what you have now, or you may end up with no useful spaces at all. Good luck!

I haven't seen a lot of poster related questions so this room does not seem likely to get momentum this early. Take it into the main chat and lets all have a go at it together.